# How do I solve this ode: $1+(y')^2=cy^{-1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I have an ODE, which is the solution to the Brachistochrone problem:
$$1+(y')^2=cy^{-1}$$

**How does one solve this?**

Can you just give me a general direction/hint, rather than a specific solution?

Comment: Catenaries, second variations, brachistochrones...you seem deep into a Calculus of Variations study session....I will post an answer soon

Comment: Write in the form $\sqrt{\frac{c-y}{y}} \frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ and make the substution $y = c \sin^2 \theta$?

Comment: @Anaedonist, haha, funny that you noticed. Yes I've been working on the calculus of variations for 10 hours today (with breaks, don't worry).

Comment: Hahah, It seems that every physicist and mathematician had solved those happy 3 friends, Brachistochrone, Dido and find the find the shortest distance on a.... problem))

Comment: Another solution: $y \left( x \right) =c$ .

Answer (score 0):

you can write $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{c-y}{y}}$$ then you will get
$$\sqrt{\frac{y}{c-y}}dy=\pm dx$$ after integrating we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{y}{c-y}} \left(\sqrt{y} (y-c)+c
   \sqrt{c-y} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{c-y}}\right)\right)
   }{\sqrt{y}}=\pm x+K$$

Comment: Happy to see your CAS is still working. What about starting to do some mathematics and posting answers not reduced to the transcription of its results?

Answer (score 0):

Use $y=c\sin^2(t)$ in
$$
\sqrt{\frac{c-y}y}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}
$$
to get
$$
\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin(t)}=2c\sin(t)\cos(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}
$$
which simplifies to
$$
1=c(1-\cos(2t))\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}
$$
giving us the parametric equation of the curve:
$$
\begin{align}
x&=c\left(t-\tfrac12\sin(2t)\right)\\
y&=c\sin^2(t)
\end{align}
$$
[image]